# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'xxx', 'xxx', and 'xxx'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How could I solve this? I saw other related posts, but the solution worked for me in some cases, when the function that I call in the useEffect is not async, but in the case of being async, I don't know how to solve it, someone who has solved it?

Although in these cases it does not work for me either...

```
useEffect(() => {
  const removeProduct = localStorage.getItem('@areRemovedProducts');
  const areRemovedProducts = removeProduct ? JSON.parse(removeProduct) : false;

  const goBack = localStorage.getItem('@goBack');
  const goBackOrderConfirmation = goBack ? JSON.parse(goBack) : false;

  const iniTialSuggestedVal: boolean =
    (props.pastRouteInfo?.cartId === props.cartModel.getId() &&
      props.pastRouteInfo?.paymentMethod === props.paymentForm &&
      !areRemovedProducts &&
      !goBackOrderConfirmation) ||
    false;
  setTimeout(() => setIsOpenModalSuggested(iniTialSuggestedVal), 500);
}, []);
```

Not in this

```
useEffect(() => {
  get();
}, []);

const get = async () => {
  const {
    match: { params },
  } = props;

  const user = localStorage.getItem('@user');
  const userId = user ? JSON.parse(user) : '';
  setUser(userId);

  const notificationsUser = await props.notification.getNotifications(
    userId.id,
  );
  const paramsId: any = params;
  const findNotifications = notificationsUser.docs.find(
    (item: any) => item._id === paramsId.id,
  );

  findNotifications !== undefined && setOpenNotification(findNotifications);
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you get an error or is it that the behavior is incorrect? For the second one, do you only want `get()` to be called once?

Comment: I want to remove this warning, without disabling the exhaustive-deps

 React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'get'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Add the required dependencies to the useEffect parámeters array.

Comment: As @ValenciaHQ said, add required fields to deps array. The first code block also have the same problem with props variable. You can solve it by adding props.notification into deps array.

The issue here is, useEffect hook has 2 different update methods. Without deps array, it updates whenever component updates, with deps array (second parameter of the hook) it only updates when variables inside deps array change. So, React is warning you about a possible bug that can result in unexpected behaviour. This behaviour is unrelated to async, applies to all variables alike.